# Retrieve product url with category in the graphQL

Tags: magento2, product, url, query, graphql

I've enabled at backoffice the usage of the category inside the product url by setting this option:
[image]

When I access the magento frontend, I can now access the product with the url `<category>/<product>`. However, when I call the graphQL API:

```
query {
    products(filter: {
        sku: {
            eq: "1"
        }
    }) {
        items {
            sku
            canonical_url
            url_path
            url_key
        }
    }
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "products": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "sku": "1",
                    "canonical_url": "tire-black",
                    "url_path": null,
                    "url_key": "tire-black"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, I get the path url with the product name only,(i.e. without the category). In the example, the product `tire-black` belongs to the category `tires`. In the `url_rewrite` table the associated url with the category is: `tires/tire-black`, which is what I want to retrieve using the graphQL.

Do you know if there's another field I should use to get the url comprehensive of the category (i.e. `tires/tire-black`)?
If not, what should I do to get it in the graphql response?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this below request in your GraphQL :

> **Query Request :**

```
query {
    products(filter: {
        sku: {
            eq: "24-MB01"
        }
    }) {
        items {
            sku
            canonical_url
            url_path
            url_key
            url_rewrites {
              url
              parameters {
                name
                value
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Response :**

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "items": [
        {
          "sku": "24-MB01",
          "canonical_url": null,
          "url_path": null,
          "url_key": "joust-duffle-bag",
          "url_rewrites": [
            {
              "url": "joust-duffle-bag.html",
              "parameters": [
                {
                  "name": "id",
                  "value": "1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "url": "gear/joust-duffle-bag.html",
              "parameters": [
                {
                  "name": "id",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "name": "category",
                  "value": "3"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "url": "gear/bags/joust-duffle-bag.html",
              "parameters": [
                {
                  "name": "id",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "name": "category",
                  "value": "4"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope, It will useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

> **try this**

```
query {
    products(filter: {
        sku: {
            eq: "1"
        }
    }) {
        items {
            categories {
              id
              name
              url_key
              url_path
              canonical_url
              include_in_menu
            }
            name
            sku
            canonical_url
            url_path
            url_key
             image{
              label
              url
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way I get the product category, not the product url with the category.

Comment: Please show what you want to show in response ?

Comment: Updated the question: I want `tires/tire-black` as url instead of just `tire-black`, where `tires` is the category.